# DropDownList with OnSelectedIndexChanged not displaying data using SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am working on an ASP.NET application and I have a DropDownList which is not displaying data from database using SqlDataReader. Below is my asp.net web form code ...

```
<p>
 <span class="label">
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Document Number" Font-Size="Small" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
 </span>
 <asp:TextBox ID="numb" runat="server" Width="176px" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
 <br />
 <br />
 <span class="label">
 <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Title" Font-Size="Small" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
 </span>
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="176px"></asp:TextBox><br/>
 <br />
 <span class="label">
 <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Author" Font-Size="Small" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
 </span>
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="176px"></asp:TextBox><br/>
 <br />
 <span class="label">
 <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Account Name" Font-Size="Small" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
 </span>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="name" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
 <asp:ListItem Text="-SELECT-" Value="" />
 </asp:DropDownList><br />
 <br />
 <span class="label">
 <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Account Code" Font-Size="Small" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
 </span>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="code" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList><br />
 <br />

 <span class="label">
 <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Date" Font-Size="Small" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
 </span>
 <asp:TextBox ID="date" runat="server" Width="176px" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox><br />
 <br />
 <asp:Label ID="results" runat="server"></asp:Label>
 </p>
```

And below is my C# code

```
if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CS))
                {
                    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT Account_Name FROM Accounts", conn);
                    conn.Open();

                    name.DataSource = comm.ExecuteReader();
                    name.DataTextField = "Account_Name";
                    name.DataValueField = "Account_Name";
                    name.DataBind();
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);
                }

                date.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                LoadDetails();
            }
        }

        protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
            string account = "SELECT Account_Code FROM Accounts WHERE Account_Name = '" + name.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand camd = new SqlCommand(account, con);
            con.Open();

            code.DataSource = camd.ExecuteReader();
            code.DataTextField = "Account_Code";
            code.DataValueField = "Account_Code";
            code.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }

        private void LoadDetails()
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString))
            {
                string docNo = Session["doc"].ToString();
                string query = "SELECT * FROM [pubs].[dbo].[ReportDocumentNo] WHERE DocumentNo = @docNo;";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@docNo", docNo);
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        numb.Text = rdr["DocumentNo"].ToString();
                        TextBox1.Text = rdr["Title"].ToString();
                        TextBox2.Text = rdr["Author"].ToString();
                        name.Text = rdr["AccName"].ToString();
                        code.Text = rdr["AccCode"].ToString();
                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

Whatever I run the page all my textboxes are populated by data from Database except *code TextBox*. What am I missing to make my *code Textbox* to display data. Thank you

Comment: First, you don't seem to have a `code` "textbox", you have a `code` "dropdownlist".  Are you getting any errors?  Does the `code` dropdown list have data in it? I would expect it to have 1 or 0 rows of data.

Comment: **<asp:DropDownList ID="code" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>** this is my code dropdownlist and I am trying to pass data from **code.Text = rdr["AccCode"].ToString();** but it doesn't show any data which is reading from the database

Answer (score 1):

Its always better to use disconnected architecture but for your answer here is the modification

I have use data table for storing purpose

```
 ASPX PAGE


 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl2"></asp:DropDownList>
```

.CS PAGE

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con3"].ConnectionString);
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string s = "select distinct IMEI_NO FROM permission";
        MySqlDataAdapter ad = new MySqlDataAdapter(s, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ad.Fill(dt);
        ddl1.DataSource = dt;
        ddl1.DataTextField = "IMEI_NO";
        ddl1.DataValueField = "IMEI_NO";
        ddl1.DataBind();
        }



protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        string s = "select distinct CA_NO FROM permission WHERE IMEI_NO='"+ddl1.SelectedItem+"'";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(s, con);
        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
        ddl2.DataSource = dt;
        ddl2.DataTextField = "CA_NO";
        ddl2.DataValueField = "CA_NO";
        ddl2.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Still You Have Problem In Code??  @Inno

Answer (score 0):

## On aspx page add this code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMealLocationQT" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMealLocationQT_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

## on Aspx.cs page

```
protected void ddlMealLocationQT_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    List<int> months = new List<int>(){1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
    foreach (string month in months)
    {
         DropDownListMonth.Items.Add(month);
    }
}
```

OR

You can use DataTextField and DataValueField properties.

```
ListControl.DataTextField Property

    DropDownList1.DataSource = drpdt; 
    DropDownList1.DataTextField="StringValue";
    DropDownList1.DataValueField="CurrencyValue";
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Or add ListItem one at a time.

https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&ufsmps=1&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=ASP%20Tutorials